# Change tab bar in the Current ViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My app has 5 tabs with each having a rootviewcontroller. Then in each tab I have multiple view controllers. I want to be in the current view controller and change the selected tab bar. 
I have tried following:

`[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];`

but it takes me to the root view of the 5th tab bar item. I want to be in the current view controller but in different tab bar item selected.

Comment: You must know that tab bar index's from 0-4 which makes your 5 tab's so you need is [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3]; as I got it from your statement. This would take you to 4th tab bar. Okay?!

Comment: I know that we have index 0-4. My concern is that I want to be in current view controller even if the selected index is changed.

Comment: I don't think so that would be possible as setselectedindex makes u go in that tab bar view. Still if you find out something do let me know.

Comment: is there any other alternative? Anything else i am trying i am getting same result.

Comment: What's point of being in same view and show different tab bar as selected ? confusing ?

Comment: For one of the controllers, the same controller can come from multiple locations but the tab bar should be same. This is the requirement.

Comment: See, this would create unnecessary mess up kinda stuff and also this is not as per design principle of tab bar but if you want to do so then you could present(not push) that common view on to tab bar controller as in that case your tab bar state would be preserved.

Comment: Fixed it with some tweak.